# Silently drop emails to specific invalid domain in Postfix?

Tags: postfix

What is the best way to have Postfix silently drop emails to a specific invalid domain?

For reasons that cannot be handled otherwise right now, our mail servers receive a lot of emails for addresses of form $userid@BLAH, where @BLAH is always that value and $userid is programmatically-generated by the sender. The sender mail servers are allowed to relay through our mail servers but since BLAH is not a valid domain, the messages get deferred with "Host or domain name not found. Name service error for name=BLAH type=MX: Host not found, try again". Obviously header_checks doesn't work since that's handled well after the hostname lookup.

I'd like to prevent these from ever getting to the queue, even though they do eventually age out after a few retries, and just silently discard them instead. (Eventually we'll get the source issue resolved but that may not be any time soon.)

**Update**
I adapted Michael's recommendation as the virtual mailbox configuration was delivering to the mailbox rather than /dev/null despite the alias. However, I was already virtual aliasing another domain, so I just added the BLAH "domain" to `virtual_alias_domains` and added `@BLAH BLAH` to `/etc/postfix/virtual`, postmapped, and along with the new `/etc/aliases` entry, it works like a charm.

**Update 2**
It occurred to me that with the addition of BLAH to `virtual_alias_domains`, a header_check rule should now work, obviating the need for the aliases in `virtual` alias `aliases`, and testing does bear this out. This has the added benefit of the emails now being logged as discards and thus picked up by the existing patterns in our Collectd tail plugin configuration for our SMTP server metrics graphs.

Comment: i´d prefer doing a whitelist of allowed domains; otherwise you are just playing a cat&mouse game.

Comment: We've only ever virtual hosted one other domain since it's closely related to the primary domain our mail servers support. This new one is a very special one-off case. That said, if I ever find a need to add any more, I will definitely switch to a whitelist-based solution rather than hard-coding the domain names in main.cf.

Comment: Without a virtual domain setup, you will continue to get these issues; Postfix is attempting to determine the delivery method, it doesn't match what you have listed in your main.cf, it doesn't see a virtual domain listed that it accepts and routes for, so it rummages around for the MX record for the domain, but it can't find one == throw an error about not being able to deliver.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, you'll need to accept mail for the nonexistent domain, e.g. by adding it to `virtual_mailbox_domains`.

Then you'll need to make a catchall address in `virtual_mailbox_maps` that delivers it locally, for example:

```
@example.com    throwaway
```

Last you need to make a local alias for `throwaway` in `/etc/aliases` that delivers mail to `/dev/null`, e.g.:

```
throwaway       /dev/null
```

Postmap and reload postfix as appropriate.

Comment: This is the correct answer (see my comment attached to the question)

Answer (score 5):

To silently drop outgoing email, you can also use transport map file

```
transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport_maps
```

containing entries like :

```
email-to-bin@example.com discard:
@domain-to-bin.com discard:
```

Comment: Can someone explain why I get "Recipient address rejected: User unknown." when I send to email-to-bin@example.com? When I cause the address to exist then it is delivered, not discarded.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine answers by Mr Goodwin and Mr Hampton into one mapping file.

```
[main.cf]
virtual_alias_maps = pcre:/etc/postfix/virtual
... # other settings

[virtual]
/^([^@]+)@invalid\b/  discard:
/^nobounce(\+[^@]+)?@/  discard:
```

This discards mail addressed to `nobounce@example.com` or `someaddress@invalid.com` as well as `nobounce+joe@other.example.org`.

Here, no separate transport map is needed, and neither is tweaking the aliases file. In fact, local delivery can be completely disabled.